# Sharpening Images with EmguCV Producing Blurred Result

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, bitmap, emgucv

I'm trying to sharpen an image using EmguCv using the following code

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> myImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(bm_dest);
CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(myImage, myImage, new Size(0, 0), 3);
Image<Bgr, byte> blur = myImage.AddWeighted(myImage, 1.5, -0.5, 0);
bm_dest = blur.Bitmap;
```

An referring this blog post http://opencv-help.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-sharpen-image-using-opencv.html

But the output image gets blurry.What im i doing wrong? Please advice.

Comment: I don't think that this is ideal way for sharpening.  Can you add your input and output images? Also try to tweak the parameters in AddWeighted()

Comment: @GarvitaTiwari I have tried convolution,but it produces out of memory exception with large images.Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388992/emgucv-out-of-memory-expcetion-in-x86-release-mode-only-sharpening-images

Answer (score -1):

You are overwriting your original image in

```
CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(myImage, myImage, new Size(0, 0), 3);
```

with the blurred image.

Try this:

CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(myImage, someNewMatrix, new Size(0, 0), 3);
Image blur = myImage.AddWeighted(someNewMatrix, 1.5, -0.5, 0);

Comment: what is the suggested matrix.I'm getting out of memory exception with convolution matrix.Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388992/emgucv-out-of-memory-expcetion-in-x86-release-mode-only-sharpening-images

Comment: sorry I don't know the emgucv details on how you have to create output mats manually or automatic.